# Add Calendar Widget to Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms, daterangepicker

I have a view on my website that uses a couple of Django forms to allow the user to specify a date range.  I was able to get it so that one Django form creates a start and end field and that when the user clicks on those fields a calendar widget (from [here](http://www.daterangepicker.com/)) pops up that allows the user to select a date range.  However, when the user selects the date range and hits "apply" the form fields aren't updated.

**EDIT**

The form I'm using looks like this:

```
class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    initial_start_date = kwargs.pop('initial_start_date')
    initial_end_date = kwargs.pop('initial_end_date')
    required_val = kwargs.pop('required')

    super(DateRangeForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.fields['start_date'].initial = initial_start_date
    self.fields['start_date'].required = required_val
    self.fields['end_date'].initial = initial_end_date
    self.fields['end_date'].required = required_val

  start_date = forms.DateField()
  end_date = forms.DateField()
```

The view they are used in looks like this:

```
def table_search(request):
  initial_start = "2015/2"
  initial_end = "2015/222"
  message = {'last_url':'table_search'}

  if request.method == "POST":
    daterange_form = DateRangeForm(request.POST,required=True,initial_start_date=initial_start,initial_end_date=initial_end)

  else:
    daterange_form = DateRangeForm(required=True,initial_start_date=initial_start,initial_end_date=initial_end)
    search_dict.update({'daterange_form':daterange_form})

  return render(request, 'InterfaceApp/table_search.html', search_dict)
```

The Django template here:

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="/InterfaceApp/home/" method="post" class="form">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="daterangepicker-container mcast-search-filter">
        <div class="daterangepicker-label">Date range:</div>
        <div id="daterange" class="daterangepicker-content">
            {% bootstrap_form daterange_form %}
            <i class="icon-calendar icon-large"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
    // the start_date and end_date are the ids that django form fields created
    $("#daterange").daterangepicker({
        locale: {
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        },
        startDate: '{{daterange_form.start_date.value}}',
        endDate: '{{daterange_form.end_date.value}}'
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT 2**

And the forms currently look like this (after @ShangWang suggestion) rendered:

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to display it so the start and end date fields show up?  I tried changing the div class so it wasn't hidden, and then they showed up but seemed superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use bootstrap-daterangepicker: https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker. It would bind the widget's change to your django form field, so you don't need to manipulate the data once it comes to the views.py.

To get more details you should download and play with it, but here's a rough idea:

Your form.py:

```
class DateRangeForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField()
    end_date = forms.DateField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # initialize the start and end with some dates
```

Your template:

```
<div class="daterangepicker-container mcast-search-filter">                                                                             
    <div class="daterangepicker-label">Date range:</div>                                                                                
    <div id="daterange" class="daterangepicker-content">                                                                                
        <i class="icon-calendar icon-large"></i>                                                                                        
        <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>                                                                                             
    </div>                                                                                                                              
</div>                                                                                                                                  

<!-- This is a hidden div that holds your form fields -->                                                                                                                                           
<div class="hide">From {{ daterange_form.start_date }} to {{ daterange_form.end_date }}</div>
```

To trigger the widget you need a javascript binding:

```
// the id_start_date and id_end_date are the ids that django form fields created
$("#daterange").initDateRangePicker("#id_start_date", "#id_end_date");
```

I created a datepicker wrapper, and defined the `initDateRangePicker` function. You should put following code in a file called `daterangepicker.js` and import that in your template as well(or simply copy it into your template):

```
(function($) {                                                                                                                                      
    $.fn.initDateRangePicker = function(start_date_el, end_date_el, future) {                                                                       
        return this.each(function() {                                                                                                               
            var start = moment($(start_date_el).val());                                                                                             
            var end = moment($(end_date_el).val());                                                                                                 

            var display_date = function(start, end) {                                                                                               
                var str = ""                                                                                                                        
                str += start.format('MMMM Do, YYYY');                                                                                               
                str += " - ";                                                                                                                       
                str += end.format('MMMM Do, YYYY');                                                                                                 

                return str;                                                                                                                         
            };                                                                                                                                      

            $(this).find("span").html(display_date(start, end));                                                                                    
            var self = this;                                                                                                                        

            if(!future) {                                                                                                                           
                $(this).daterangepicker({                                                                                                           
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',                                                                                                           
                    timePicker: false,                                                                                                              
                    ranges: {                                                                                                                       
                        'Last 7 days': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],                                                                    
                        'Month to date': [                                                                                                          
                            moment().startOf('month'),                                                                                              
                            moment(),                                                                                                               
                        ],                                                                                                                          
                        'Last Month': [                                                                                                             
                            moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'),                                                                         
                            moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month'),                                                                           
                        ]                                                                                                                           
                    },                                                                                                                              
                }, function(start, end) {                                                                                                           
                    $(start_date_el).val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));                                                                               
                    $(end_date_el).val(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));                                                                                   

                    $(self).find("span").html(display_date(start, end));                                                                            
                });                                                                                                                                 
            }                                                                                                                                       
            else {                                                                                                                                  
                 $(this).daterangepicker({                                                                                                          
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',                                                                                                           
                    timePicker: false,                                                                                                              
                    ranges: {                                                                                                                       
                        'Next 7 days': [moment().add('days', 1), moment().add('days', 7)],                                                          
                        'Next month': [                                                                                                             
                            moment().add('month', 1).startOf('month'),                                                                              
                            moment().add('month', 1).endOf('month'),                                                                                
                        ],                                                                                                                          
                    },                                                                                                                              
                }, function(start, end) {                                                                                                           
                    $(start_date_el).val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));                                                                               
                    $(end_date_el).val(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));                                                                                   

                    $(self).find("span").html(display_date(start, end));                                                                            
                });                                                                                                                                 

            }                                                                                                                                       
        });                                                                                                                                         
    };                                                                                                                                              
}).call(this, jQuery);
```

Comment: So on submit this form would return two values then correct?  Like this: `start,end = DateRangeForm(request.POST)`?  Also is it standalone or used in conjunction with my current forms?

Comment: What I'm trying to say in my answer is that you should define ONE form with two `DateField` as start date and end date. Making two separate forms instead of two fields for a start date and an end date doesn't make sense. The library I suggested only  make your template look more user-friendly, but it works well if you follow my example.

Comment: Yes, I started playing with it but when I select a date range in the calendar dropdown it doesn't update my fields.  I will post an edit to the question so it's easier to see.

Comment: You should look at my answer again, I'm using `initDateRangePicker()` to bind the widget to django fields. The two ids are the two textbox ids from django fields. You need to check the page source to get the ids, but most likely they should be `#id_start_date` and `#id_end_date`.

Comment: I tried that but it errored saying that `initDateRangePicker()` didn't exist

Comment: Ah, sorry I wrote a wrapper long time ago and I thought it was built-in function. I updated the answer, see if that would work.

Comment: I also don't seem to be able to get a time out of it.  Even with `timePicker` set to `true`